# TCP client on win service

Tags: c#, tcp, streamreader

Im connecting to a TcpClient and using StreamReader to ReadLine.
My application fetch emails every 2 seconds. 
When I run my application on desktop it works fine, but if I run it as a win service it hangs on "info = _Reader.ReadLine();" before it returns the "info" to "CheckResultOK(info);" every minute.
What causes this major delay?

I have current code:

```
   string info = "";

            _Connection = new TcpClient(Host, Port);

            if (!Ssl)
            {
                _Stream = _Connection.GetStream();
            }
            else
            {
                _Stream = new SslStream(_Connection.GetStream(), false);
                ((SslStream)_Stream).AuthenticateAsClient(Host);
            }


                _Reader = new StreamReader(_Stream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

                info = _Reader.ReadLine();

                CheckResultOK(info);
```